# Using % wildcard with pg8000

Tags: python, pg8000

I have a query similar to below:

```
def connection():
    pcon = pg8000.connect(host='host', port=1234, user='user', password='password', database = 'database')
    return pcon, pcon.cursor()

pcon, pcur = connection()
query = """ SELECT * FROM db WHERE (db.foo LIKE 'string-%' OR db.foo LIKE 'bar-%')"""
db = pd.read_sql_query(query, pcon)
```

However when I try to run the code I get:

`DatabaseError: '%'' not supported in a quoted string within the query string`

I have tried escaping the symbol with \ and an additional % with no luck. How can I get pg8000 to treat this as a wildcard properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"In Python, `%` usually refers to a variable that follows the string. If you want a literal percent sign, then you need to double it. `%%`"

-- [Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/Gys8B5Y_hIQ)

```
LIKE 'string-%%'
```

Otherwise, if that doesn't work, PostgreSQL also supports [underscores for pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

```
'abc' LIKE 'abc'    true
'abc' LIKE 'a%'     true
'abc' LIKE '_b_'    true
```

But, as mentioned in the comments,

> An underscore (_) in `pattern` stands for (matches) any single character; a percent sign (%) matches any sequence of zero or more characters

---

According to the [source code](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000/blob/master/pg8000/core.py#L504-L515), though, it would appear the problem is the single quote following the `%` in your `LIKE` statement.

```
if next_c == "%":
    in_param_escape = True
else:
    raise InterfaceError(
        "'%" + next_c + "' not supported in a quoted "
        "string within the query string")
```

So if `next_c == "'"` instead of `next_c == "%"`, then you would get your error

```
'%'' not supported in a quoted string within the query string
```

Comment: `_` is very different from `%`, they can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: @VincentSavard - Updated

Comment: Using %% in replace of % I get back a query that is completely empty even though I can see that it should be bringing back some results.

Comment: Well, at least it doesn't throw an error. So you're saying directly querying that table (outside of python) with the mentioned LIKE statement yields correct results?

Comment: For me it does.

Answer (score 1):

With a recent version of pg8000 you shouldn't have any problems with a `%` in a `LIKE`. For example:

```
>>> import pg8000.dbapi
>>>
>>> con = pg8000.dbapi.connect(user="postgres", password="cpsnow")
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE book (id SERIAL, title TEXT)")
>>> for title in ("Ender's Game", "The Magus"):
...     cur.execute("INSERT INTO book (title) VALUES (%s)", [title])
>>>
>>> cur.execute("SELECT * from book WHERE title LIKE 'The %'")
>>> cur.fetchall()
([2, 'The Magus'],)
```